# BeautifulSoup - Indeed Scraper issue

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I hope it's okay I ask this here. I have an indeed scraper in python using bs4, and until recently all was working fine, but now I get the following error after a few runs, which  causes it to crash:

**Traceback (most recent call last):
File "indeed/indeed.py", line 53, in 
link = jobs.a['href']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable**

The code itself is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests
import time

pages = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70]


titleList = []
companyList = []
locList = []
salList = []
#linkList = []
descList = []


for page in pages:
   source = requests.get('https://www.indeed.co.uk/renewable-energy-Jobs'.format(page)).text

   soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

   #print ('Page: %s' %page)

   results = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "result"})

   for jobs in soup.find_all(class_='result'):

           try:
               title = jobs.find('a', rel='noopener').text.strip()
           except Exception as e:
               title = None
           print('Title:', title)


           try:
               company = jobs.find('span', class_='company').text.strip()
           except Exception as e:
               company = None
           print('Company:', company)

           try:
               location = jobs.find('span', class_='location').text.strip()
           except Exception as e:
               location = None
           print('Location:', location)

           try:
               salary = jobs.find('span', class_='no-wrap').text.strip()
           except Exception as e:
               salary = None
           print('Salary:', salary)

           link = jobs.a['href']
           if 'http' not in link:
               link = ("https://www.indeed.co.uk" + link)
           print('Link:', link)

           page = requests.get(link)
           soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
           try:
               job_description = soup.find('div', id='jobDescriptionText').decode_contents(formatter="html")
           except Exception as e:
               job_description = None
           print('job_description:', job_description)

           titleList.append(title)
           companyList.append(company)
           locList.append(location)
           salList.append(salary)
           #linkList.append(link)
           descList.append(job_description)

           print('--------')

           time.sleep(0.5)

df = pd.DataFrame({
       'Title':titleList,
       'Company':companyList,
       'Location':locList,
       'Salary':salList,
       #'Link':linkList,
       'Description':descList})

df.to_csv('indeed.csv',index=False)
```

I've tried rewriting it the section in various ways but seems to make it worse. What has made it crash? Would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0):

Change the URL you're trying to format. Also, for job title search for `<a>` with `class="jobtitle"`, the same for `link`

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests
import time

pages = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70]


titleList = []
companyList = []
locList = []
salList = []
# linkList = []
descList = []


for page in pages:
    # change URL:
    source = requests.get(
        "https://uk.indeed.com/jobs?q=renewable+energy&start={}".format(page)
    ).text

    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")

    # print ('Page: %s' %page)

    results = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "result"})

    for jobs in soup.find_all(class_="result"):

        try:
            title = jobs.find("a", class_="jobtitle").text.strip()
        except Exception as e:
            title = None
        print("Title:", title)

        try:
            company = jobs.find("span", class_="company").text.strip()
        except Exception as e:
            company = None
        print("Company:", company)

        try:
            location = jobs.find("span", class_="location").text.strip()
        except Exception as e:
            location = None
        print("Location:", location)

        try:
            salary = jobs.find("span", class_="no-wrap").text.strip()
        except Exception as e:
            salary = None
        print("Salary:", salary)

        link = jobs.find("a", class_="jobtitle")["href"]
        if "http" not in link:
            link = "https://www.indeed.co.uk" + link
        print("Link:", link)

        page = requests.get(link)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
        try:
            job_description = soup.find(
                "div", id="jobDescriptionText"
            ).decode_contents(formatter="html")
        except Exception as e:
            job_description = None
        print("job_description:", job_description)

        titleList.append(title)
        companyList.append(company)
        locList.append(location)
        salList.append(salary)
        # linkList.append(link)
        descList.append(job_description)

        print("--------")

        time.sleep(0.5)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Title": titleList,
        "Company": companyList,
        "Location": locList,
        "Salary": salList,
        #'Link':linkList,
        "Description": descList,
    }
)

print(df)
df.to_csv("indeed.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: It seems to do the same as before: works well for a few runs, then:

Title: None
Company: None
Location: None
Salary: None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../indeed/indeed.py", line 56, in <module>
    link = jobs.find("a", class_="jobtitle")["href"]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 0):

I've updated the find parameters and specified the exceptions.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests
import time

pages = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70]

titleList = []
companyList = []
locList = []
salList = []
# linkList = []
descList = []

for page in pages:
    source = requests.get("https://uk.indeed.com/jobs?q=renewable+energy&start={}".format(page)).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

    # print ('Page: %s' %page)

    results = soup.findAll("ul", {"class": "jobsearch-ResultsList"})

    for jobs in soup.find_all(class_='job_seen_beacon'):

        try:
            title = jobs.find('div', class_='singleLineTitle').text.strip()
        except (TypeError, AttributeError):
            title = None
        print('Title:', title)

        try:
            company = jobs.find('span', class_='companyName').text.strip()
        except (TypeError, AttributeError):
            company = None
        print('Company:', company)

        try:
            location = jobs.find('div', class_='companyLocation').text.strip()
        except (TypeError, AttributeError):
            location = None
        print('Location:', location)

        try:
            salary = jobs.find('div', class_='salaryOnly').text.strip()
        except (TypeError, AttributeError):
            salary = None
        print('Salary:', salary)

        link = jobs.a['href']
        if 'http' not in link:
            link = ("https://www.indeed.co.uk" + link)
        print('Link:', link)

        page = requests.get(link)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
        try:
            job_description = soup.find('div', id='jobDescriptionText').decode_contents(formatter="html")
        except (TypeError, AttributeError):
            job_description = None
        print('job_description:', job_description)

        titleList.append(title)
        companyList.append(company)
        locList.append(location)
        salList.append(salary)
        # linkList.append(link)
        descList.append(job_description)

        print('--------')

        time.sleep(0.5)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Title': titleList,
    'Company': companyList,
    'Location': locList,
    'Salary': salList,
    # 'Link':linkList,
    'Description': descList})

df.to_csv('indeed.csv', index=False)
```